# How to format brackets for day in setNumberFormat?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use setNumberFormat() in a script, like this (for a date value that has been copied before) :

```
sh2.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
```

So I get this in the cell, which is fine :

**08/03/2023**

Problem is I'd like to also have the day between brackets, like this (here the day is in french) :

**08/03/2023 [mer.]**

So I tried to change my code like this :

```
sh2.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy ddd \[ddd\]');
```

Which is what I found [in the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_time_format_examples).

But it does not work : I get a **#VALUE!** error.

Now if I do the same, but without the brackets, the day is displayed correctly :

```
sh2.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy ddd');
```

So here I get :

**08/03/2023 mer.**

Also tried like this for the brackets, just in case…

```
sh2.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy ddd [ddd]');
```

But then I also get a **#VALUE!** error.

So would you know how to get the brackets ?

Comment: The answers use different methodologies to deliver an answer, and as a result the returned values are slightly different. FWIW, the answer by @TheWizEd returns a date. The answer by ab.it.gcp returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the brackets as shown below.

```
sh2.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy ddd \\[ddd\\]');
```

Comment: I found that `"dd/MM/yyyy \\[ddd\\]"` yields "08/03/2023 [Wed]". I do NOT understand why one must have two escape characters - seems to be inconsistent with documentation, BUT at least it works.

Comment: Oh thank you a lot @TheWizEd !! This is really great. And as Tedinoz says it is not consistent with documentation…

Answer (score 1):

Try the below approach

```
  var date = sheet.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).getValue();
  var val = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy [E]");
  sheet.getRange(headingRow+1, dateCol).setValue(val);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ab.it.gcp, I tried this but I have another message error which is :
"Exception: Les paramètres (String,String,String) ne correspondent pas à la signature de la méthode "Utilities.formatDate"."
(Sorry, in french)

Comment: The first parameter passed in Utiltities.formatDate  should be of type date. Make sure that your cell value contains date value and not sheet.

Comment: Typo in above comment: Should be "not string" instead of "not sheet".
If you want to keep the cell value of type string, then convert it to date in apps script and then pass it into Utilities.formatDate.

Comment: I wonder, did you mean ` var val = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy [E]");`

Comment: I meant `var val = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy [ddd]");`. Updated 'dd' to 'ddd' in the answer.
Assuming the requirement is to show something like "17/05/2022 [Mon]" on the sheet

Comment: `[ddd]` - in my test of your code, this returns [008]. Your approach uses the [Java SE SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) where "d" = "Day in month" but "E" = "Day name in week".

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking. So 'E' needs to be used instead of 'ddd'. Updated my answer.